# Python paramiko failed to connect in CMD

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have some lines of Python scripts using Paramiko to setup an SSH connection, the script is as follows,

```
import paramiko

self.SSH_CLIENT = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.SSH_CLIENT.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.SSH_CLIENT.connect(ip, port, username, password, timeout=10)
self.LOCAL_IP = self.SSH_CLIENT.get_transport().getpeername()
```

and that script works fine in Eclipse with PyDev, however, when it's called in CMD, the script got stuck in

```
self.SSH_CLIENT.connect(ip, port, username, password, timeout=10)
```

without any error information. Could someone tell me why and how to solve it?

Comment: What is CMD? By *got stuck*, do you mean it just waits forever*?

Comment: Sorry may be my words made you confused, when i said CMD, i mean this script is called in command prompt, and got stuck means it just waits forever, like you said. Don't know why.